# Is there a way to know whether the browser notification are enabled or not?

Tags: javascript, browser, push-notification

I'm working on push notifications and I've successfully implemented it, but I'm stuck at one point where I want to show whether the browser notifications are enabled or not.

Let's say I'm currently using Windows 11 and I've disabled notifications for browser from `System > Notifications > Google Chrome`. Now, when a user visits settings page(for the status of push notification) in a website in their browser, I want show the status of whether notifications are enabled or disabled for the browser to the user?

I've been searching for several hours and everywhere I look, I only find `Notification.permission`, but it only tells whether notifications are enabled or not for the website in a browser, not for the browser itself.

Comment: AFAIK, the browser does not have access to system settings. So, you cannot get that information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PrerakSola, it seems that this is the case. GPT also says the same thing, that we can't get system level notifications because they are controlled by user.